# Zooming on Xcode on Mac

Tags: macos, xcode, zoom

I have seen in many tutorial videos people zoom in and out on Xcode to show the code a little better. I tried with 'control' + 'two finger swipe on trackpad' but this does not work on Xcode. What is the shortcut for zooming on Xcode?

Comment: Care to point to one of those videos? Zoom in OS X means probably a different thing.

Comment: MAC is a make up company, I'm assuming you're talking about a mac and/or Mac?

Comment: Yes. I am using MacBook Pro.

Comment: It's probably a feature of their screen capture software.

Comment: It's probably a feature of the capture software, but screen zoom is still a Mac OS feature.  You can enable if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Screen Zoom is a system-wide feature. In Lion, this is part of Universal Access.

The short version is:

Visit System Preferences->Universal Access->Seeing

And set "Zoom" to on.

You'll then be able to scroll using the control key and the scroll gesture of your input device.

Follow [the instructions here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/02/enable-screen-zoom-in-mac-os-x-lion/) for more detailed instructions.